# Harmonics in neutral conductor

Tags: harmonics

[image]

[image]

If he multiplied the 10 A by 3 this means each phase has 10 A of harmonics. So, shouldn't they cancel out at the neutral just like the rated frequency currents?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because homework needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: I personally think this is borderline on the acceptable side and am hence voting to reopen. The screenshot given is of the answer key rather than a bare question, and there's an attempt to explain the phenomenon in order to understand the given solution, although it's minimal at the moment. To OP: try writing out the actual time domain equation of each current, and solve KCL at the source or load. You'll see some components cancel numerically, while others remain. If you get stuck, [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation for a star system ... simplified, balanced charge.

Multiple of third hamonics give a neutral current.

[image]